# Object of type 'MyClass' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]' C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, exception, reflection, methodinfo

I've been looking into this for a couple of hours but so far haven't gotten any luck.
Here's my C# code:

```
myClassInstance = new MyClass("MyParam", 1);
object[] args = new object[1] { myClassInstance };

MethodInfo methodInfo = GetType().GetMethod(myMethod, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
string method = (string)methodInfo.Invoke(this, args);
```

I have MethodInfo and System.Reflection imported. The Unity error is this:

```
ArgumentException: Object of type 'SystemController' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'
```

It doesn't point to a specific line in the code, but from what I can tell it seems to be an issue with converting the myClassInstance variable to an object, which doesn't make sense to me, as I believed everything in C# inherited from System.Object.

Here is MyClass:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string var1;
    public int var2;

    public MyClass(string param1, int param2) 
    {
        var1 = param1;
        var2 = param2;
    }
}
```

Clearly, I'm not showing the entire class, but the only difference is that there are more variables and parameters to store. Those shouldn't change anything, so I won't bore you with them. It's just a class with a constructor, not inheriting from anything.
Any help I could get with this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: just to point out, even if this is true "everything in C# inherited from System.Object", won't match System.Object[] (notice the array [])

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid; I don't code much C#. Would removing `new object[1]` and adding a typecast `(object)` before `myClassInstance` work, on the second line?

Comment: don't worry, no one is stupid here ^^ With this code is hard for me to tell if it will work or not with those changes. But your error is saying something about SystemController, which I can't see on your post :S

Answer (score 1):

The error here was me trying to pass the entire object[] array into my method as a parameter when I should have only passed the contents of the array. See here:

I was doing this:

```
void MyMethod(object[] args) {
    MyClass instance = (MyClass)args[0];
    ...
}
```

But should've done this:

```
void MyMethod(MyClass myClassInstance) {
    ...
}
```

After reading some more documentation and reviewing the comments above I discovered that the .Invoke() method passes what's *inside* the args array instead of the entire array. At least, that's my current understanding, and it's what made my code work.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes the arguments are passed one by one. E.g. `object[]{"hi", 4, List<float>{1,2,3}}` would expect the signature of `MyMethod(string, int, List<float>)`